# P Pavilion 1330 freezes during 16.04 install

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb, hp, hardware-test

HP Pavilion 1330 (AMD-Athlon64\3GB-RAM\250GB-HDD) install freezes during installation.  Attempts include form DVD and USB.  Lubuntu USB install was successful.

## QUESTIONS

1) Is there a litmus test(s) that can be performed on the PC to determine if it is a failure to meet a requirement?

2) Is this model known to be problematic or can anyone confirm that they have had success with this model.  Maybe this problem is unique to 16.04?

Any diagnostic suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but I would stick to Lubuntu, especially with that hardware. What errors are you experiencing in the install? Does it simply just freeze?

Comment: @PatrickNegus I suspect that I will have to settle for Lubuntu.  The screen simply freezes.  RAM test shows no failures.